# Heroku deployment times out at "Cleaning up the bundler cache."

Tags: caching, heroku, timeout, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to deploy a project to Heroku.

The project has previously been successfully deployed, but now I get the following output when deploying:

```
   [...]
   Using rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
   Using rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
   Using rspec (2.8.0)
   Using bundler (1.1.rc.7)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile /tmp/build_465ucsomkafs /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=580.2929985523224 (Utils::TimeoutError)
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `loop'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:48:in `block in spawn'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:44:in `popen'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:44:in `spawn'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `block in compile'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:33:in `fork'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:33:in `compile'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:464:in `block in run_buildpack'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:702:in `log'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:463:in `run_buildpack'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `block in timeout'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `rescue in timeout'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:93:in `timeout'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:96:in `block in compile'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:702:in `log'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:95:in `compile'
from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in <main>'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:472:in `block in lock'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:472:in `lock'
from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>'
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

We have pinpointed the line in Gemfile that causes this to be:

```
gem 'internal-lib', :git => 'https://username:password@github.com/Projectname/internal-lib'
```

When bundler installs the gem it looks alright:

```
   Fetching https://username:password@github.com/Projectname/internal-lib
```

In what ways can a successfully bundled gem cause the "Cleaning up the bundler cache" step to timeout?

We have tried to include the gem in other ways, as a raw copy of the repo in vendor/private and as a git submodule in vendor/private but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a problem with Heroku. Today the deploy worked again, without changes from our side...

Comment: How did you pinpoint the gem causing the issue? I've been trying to solve the same issue for 3 days now 0_o